# Save Data Into Table Before Deleting

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a detailview that has the Delete button; when user clicks the Delete button they get  the delete confirmation dialog box. What kind of command do i need to use in the detailview before the data gets deleted?  When user selects "Yes" i want to save the data in the detailview into some kind of variable first then delete it.  I want to get some kind of high level guidance or some hint.  thanks
Here is the code for the confirmation dialog box in my ASPX file.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
    &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                      CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete');" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to the `ItemDeleting` event, or even the `ItemCommand` event.

In both you will still be able to access the data *before* it is deleted.